# Sum and subtract using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return only one result, I need to sum all the states `(1, 3)` and `(2, 4, 5)` then subtract each total Example:

```
cashtransaction_amount, cashtransactionstatus_id
50.00                   1 (+)
39.99                   2 (-)
330.70                  3 (+)
10.00                   5 (-)
50.50                   4 (-)
30.00                   2 (-)

Sum(1,3): 50.00 + 330.70 = 380.70
Sum(2, 5, 4): 39.99 + 10.00 + 50.50 + 30.00 = 130.49
Final Result Sum(1,3) - Sum(2, 5, 4): 380.70 - 130.49 = 250.21
```

I tryed:

```
(from DataRow Transaction_DataRow in Dt_transaction.AsEnumerable()
where Transaction_DataRow.Field<Int32>("cashpaymenttype_id") == 1 // Cash Money
group Transaction_DataRow by Transaction_DataRow.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id") into tmp
select new
    {
        cashtransaction_amount = tmp.Sum(x => (x.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id") == 1 || x.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id") == 3) ? x.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount") : -x.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount"))
    }).Aggregate(Transaction_DataTable, (dt, result) => { dt.Rows.Add(result.cashtransaction_amount); return dt; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be:

```
total = tmp.Select(b =>
           {
               var id = b.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id");
               return (id == 1 || id == 3 ? 1 : -1) *
                      b.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount");
           }).Sum();
```

Or:

```
total = tmp.Sum(b => (new[]{1,3}.Contains(b.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id"))
                          ? 1 : -1) * b.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help you can tell me where is the `b` var is defined? because i get the following error: `The name 'b' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: The x was supposed to be a b. Fixed

Comment: Friend tried in various ways your example and always gives me a bad result, could please give me the complete example applied to my code? Thanks

Comment: Than you @Yorye Nathan, you helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
cashtransaction_amount = tmp.Aggregate((a,b) =>
    {
        var id = b.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id");
        var amt = b.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount");
        return id == 1 || id == 3 ? a + amt : a - amt;
    });
```

Comment: Hy Thank you for your help but i get this error: `Error 3 Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.DataRow' and 'double'`

Comment: try casting id and amt like this `int32 id = b.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id") as int32;` `double amt = b.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount") as double;`

Comment: or like this `int32 id = (int32)b.Field<Int32>("cashtransactionstatus_id");` `double amt = (double)b.Field<Double>("cashtransaction_amount");`

Comment: But i ask you.. why use int32 *and* double? why not just use 1 of them?

Comment: Well, because the `id` is an `int` and the `amount` is a `double`. That makes sense. Jonathan, your error might be solved by using different overload of the `Aggregate` method in which you specify an initial seed value (giving it `0d` might make the compiler understand that `a` is a `double` as well). Another option can be found in my answer which does basically the same, in a different approach.

Comment: @Andrew the field `cashtransactionstatus_id` is a INT type and `cashtransaction_amount` is DOUBLE Type into the database, my friend.